# SQL Server 2012 remote restart or stop service

Tags: sql-server, service, sql-server-2012, ssms, privileges

I want to remote restart or stop SQL server service  on SSMS. When I login in a DB using sa account, the menu bar still be disabled

I looked up some information, MS seems to disable it for security reasons from  SQL server 2012

If there is any possible, I can alter some system settings to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So to stop/restart an SQL Server instance from Object Explorer in SSMS, you would have to met the following requirements:
1. You must have to have at least public server role on the SQL Server instance.
2. You must have the privilege to [start/stop](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5752.how-to-grant-users-rights-to-manage-services-start-stop-etc.aspx) services on the server that hosts SQL Server instance. For example, add your windows user to administrator group on the server.

Also,since SA uses SQL authentication, the best you can do is issue a [SHUTDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188767.aspx) command to stop SQL Server.

Comment: Finally, I found it's a bug in sql server 2012 ssms, when I used another version ssms like 2008, it was ok!